# How can I visualize the map of Google Maps in React?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I am trying to create a component which is a visualization of a map of Google Maps.
This is without using the `google-map-react` library since I want to make my own component

```
import React from 'react'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
let map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
  });
}
export default function GoogleMap() {
    return (
        <>
            <Helmet>
                <script defer
                    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&callback=initMap">
                </script>
            </Helmet>
            <div id="map"></div>
        </>
    )
}
```

This is the code I am using, but for some reason it is not painting anything and I get corset request errors, honestly I am lost in this, could someone help me? at least to know what my mistake is

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&callback=initMap'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
> this is the error message i get and this is where i wonder.

Do I need to make a request with fetch instead of directly using the script?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code however, I get a different error which is `initMap is not a function`. It seems that the callback from the script is looking for the initMap function that should be tied to the window `window.initMap`. You can achieve this by declaring a `window.initMap` function inside the `GoogleMap` function. Here's a [working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cc1kkw?file=src/App.js) and code snippet below:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import './style.css'
let map;

export default function GoogleMap() {

 if (typeof window != "undefined") {
    window.initMap = () => {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
  })
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Helmet>
                <script defer
                    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initMap">
                </script>
            </Helmet>
            <div id="map"></div>
        </>
    )
}
}
```

*Note: Don't forget to assign dimensions value to your div classes in your css sheet.*